# Basics of calculating a definite integral

Tags: calculus, integration

How can an evaluate this integral? $$\int_5^9 3x^2dx$$

I know how to evaluate $$\int 3x^2dx=3(x^3/3)=x^3$$

But I don't know how to make the first one.

Comment: Google "definite integral" and/or "Riemann Integral", y then "Fundamental theorem of Integral Calculus".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [fundamental theorem of calculus](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fundamental_theorem_of_calculus): $$\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\mathrm{F}(b)-\mathrm{F}(a)$$ where $\mathrm F(x)$ is the antiderivative of $f(x)$, which is in your example $x^3$ (nb: I'm assuming you were given $\rm C=0$).

I hope this helps.
Best wishes, $\mathcal H$akim.

Answer (score 1):

It is good of you to try and learn on your own, but a word of warning: be systematic about it.

You actually made a mistake, as
$\int 3x^2dx$ equals $x^3 + C$ and not just $x^3$.

The second part is that there is a major difference between $$\int f(x) dx$$ and $$\int_a^bf(x)d(x).$$The first is defined as "any differentiable function $F$ for which the equality $F'=f$ holds". The second is defined as "the area under the graph of the function $f$". The fundamental theorem of calculus tells you that, for a continuous function $f$ and a differentiable function $F$ for which $F'=f$, you can calculate $$\int_a^b f(x)dx$$ simply by calculating $F(b) - F(a)$.

I advise you to do some more reading on this subject. This is very fundamental stuff you *must* graps if you want to learn some truly cool analysis.

Comment: Be careful about "the area under the graph". This would be $\int_a^b |f(x)| dx$, note the absolute value.

Comment: I think you made a mistake, it is $\rm F(b)-F(a)$ and not the opposite. ;)

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع Indeed, I corrected this. AlexR, I didn't want to evercomplicate things. It is clear enough for the OP to read more.

Comment: @AlexR We would also have to assume that $b\gt a$ since if the opposite is true then $\int_a^b|f(x)|dx=-\int_b^a|f(x)|\,\mathrm dx\leqslant0$. Another option is simply to put an absolute value to the hole integral $|\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx|$.

Comment: @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع Actually, $|\int_a^b |f(x)| dx|$ is needed, cf $f(x) = \sin x, (a,b) = (0,2\pi)$.

Comment: @AlexR Good point.

Answer (score 1):

We just need, now, to evaluate the integral at $x = 9$ and $x = 5$, subtracting its value at $5$ from its value at $9$. If we call the integrated function $x^3 = F(x)$, then to evaluate the *definite* integral, we calculate $$\int_a^b f(x)\,dx = F(x) \;\Big|_{b}^a = F(b) - F(a)$$

---

$$\begin{align}\int_5^9 3x^2dx\quad  &= \quad\dfrac{3x^3}{3}\;\Big|_5^9 \\ \\ 
&= \quad x^3\;\Big|_5^9 \\ \\ & = \quad((9)^3 - (5)^3) \\ \\ &= 729-125=604\end{align}$$

Comment: Dear @amWhy, your answer is correct but you wrote down the FTC statement in an opposite way:  $\int_a^b f(x)\,\mathrm dx=\mathrm{F}(b)-\mathrm{F}(a)$ and not $\mathrm{F}(a)-\mathrm{F}(b)$. ;)

Comment: Thanks, @حكيمالفيلسوفالضائع